# WordPress Custom Post Type With Custom Meta: Foreach Only Looping Once

Tags: php, html, wordpress, foreach, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called 'reviews' which has custom meta data (_field_1, _field_1_comments, _field_2, _field_2_comments etc).
I'm using the [Insert PHP Code Snippet](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/) to pull a PHP snippet onto a specific page. The snippet is supposed to find the last three reviews in a category and display their custom meta. Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
$rev = array(
    "_field_1" => "This is the first field name:",
    "_field_2" => "This is the second field name:",
    "_field_3" => "This is the third field name:",
    "_field_4" => "This is the fourth field name:",
    "_field_5" => "This is the fifth field name:"
);

$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=reviews&cat=2');
$l = 4; ?>

<div class="feed review-feed">
    <table>
        <tr class="title">
            <td class="section">
                <h4>Fields:</h4>
            </td>
            <?php $i = 1;
            while ($my_query->have_posts() && $i < 4) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <td>
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                </td>
            <?php $i++; endwhile ?>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($rev as $field => $name) {
            $my_query->the_post();

            $comments = $field . '_comments';

            $ratings = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $field, true);
            $comment = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $comments, true); ?>

            <tr>
                <td class="section">
                    <span><?php echo $name; ?></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="review-rating">
                        <span><?php echo $ratings; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="review-comment">
                        <?php echo $comment; ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
<?php
```

The foreach seems to be working as every single field name ($name) is displaying but only the first two fields ($ratings) are being displayed and only the very first comment ($comment) is being displayed.

Also, the foreach is not getting ANY html for any posts apart from the first one. I think there must be something wrong with my foreach but I cannot see what.

Comment: I think your issue is with `get_the_ID()`. Can you check what the output of this function is ? (`print_r('Working with ID: ' . get_the_ID();`)

Comment: The output of that function was the following: (`Working with ID: 1285 Working with ID: 1282 Working with ID: Working with ID: Working with ID:`)

Comment: So as you see only two ID's are returned which means the other 3 get_post_meta() will not return any results. Have you found a solution meanwhile?

Comment: I see, but why would the first two work but not the others? If the foreach loop was broken then surely it wouldn't loop at all? As for a solution, I haven't made any progress.